# error executing $jekyll serve --watch --baseurl ""

Tags: jekyll

I want to make a  blog using Jekyll , so have made a public repository in my github account and made gh-pages branch and set it to default branch  and later deleted master branch . Also, I have made _config.yml file whose contents are as follows.

```
markdown:redcarpet 
baseurl:/amar
exclude:['readme.md']
```

when I want to turn on Jekyll , using this command

```
$jekyll serve --watch --baseurl ""
```

I am getting this error

```
dhcp-54-132:amar Amar$ jekyll serve --watch --baseurl " "
           WARNING: Error reading configuration. Using defaults (and options).
Configuration file: (INVALID) /Users/Amar/Documents/jekyll-blog/amar/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/Amar/Documents/jekyll-blog/amar
       Destination: /Users/Amar/Documents/jekyll-blog/amar/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.062 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/Amar/Documents/jekyll-blog/amar'
           WARNING: Error reading configuration. Using defaults (and options).
Configuration file: (INVALID) /Users/Amar/Documents/jekyll-blog/amar/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000 /
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

Can someone please help me, also as I am new to Jekyll , so please do not downvote me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a space for the options and its values

> markdown:redcarpet

should be

> markdown: redcarpet

and so on in _config.yml file

Comment: It worked for me ; thanks a lot for resolving my issue

Answer (score 0):

There should be space after tags in .`yml` file, and this has to be  done for all of the tags.